# Can't hide a sidebar in a webBrowser control programatically

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

Inside the `DocumentCompleted` event after loading a [page](http://www.csgodouble.com/) in my webBrowser control in winforms I am trying to hide the sidebar with `id=pullout`.

```
var divs = webBrowser.Document?.GetElementsByTagName("div");
if (divs == null) return;

foreach (var pulloutDiv in divs.Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(h => h.Id == "pullout"))
{
    pulloutDiv.SetAttribute("class", "hidden");
}
```

But this doesn't do anything. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Is it because the page has already been loaded any changes made to html are ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change class to className:

```
foreach (var pulloutDiv in divs.Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(h => h.Id == "pullout"))
{
    pulloutDiv.SetAttribute("className", "hidden");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, but why `className` rather than `class`? What would I use if wanted to change a `margin` attribute value?

Comment: well microsoft has its own mysteries!! ;) I had a hard time to discover it too ;)

Comment: Ok, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) actually mentions the `className`